# Create a dictionary with a HTML-form in Django

Tags: html, django, templates, post, dictionary

Is there any possible method to create a form with one or more elements like:

```
<form action="{% url "foo" %}" method="POST">
    <div id="report_item">
        <input type="text" name="dontknow">
        <input type="date" name="dontknow">
    </div>
    <div id="report_item">
        <input type="text" name="dontknow">
        <input type="date" name="dontknow">
    </div>
</form>
```

And to get a dictionary from this form as below:

```
{data:
   {1: {
        text: 'bla', date: '2014-03-02'
   },
   {2: {
        text: 'second text', date: '2014-03-01'
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite, but you probably want to look at [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/). That gives you a series of repeated forms, which you can output on the template by just iterating through. Once you've validated the POST data if you really need a dictionary you can do something like:

```
data = {i: form.cleaned_data for i, form in enumerate(formset.forms)}
```